# Refer to an object by using a name in a string android

Tags: java, android, string

I want to be able to use an object in java by using names stored in variables. For example :

```
String[] str={"name1","name2"};
Button name1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but1);
Button name2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but2);

//what i want to do is : instead of
name1.setText("TEXT");

//to use something like
Button.str[0].setText("TEXT");
```

Comment: why not just have an array of buttons, or objects if it must be multi types. or you could use some kind of hashtable or dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a Map ?

```
Map<String,Button> buttons = new HashMap<String,Button>();
buttons.put("buttonA", new Button());
buttons.get("buttonA");  // gets the button...
```

Answer (score 0):

The smartest way for you to do this would be to use a key,value data structure to do a look up of the Button.

I always use HashMap because it is a O(1) look up time.

Heres a quick example:

```
HashMap<String, Button> map = new HashMap<String, Button>();

Button name1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but1);
map.put("name1", name1);

Button name2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but2);
map.put("name2", name2);

map.get("name1"); //Will return button name1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `HashMap<String, Button>`. This provides lookups in `O(1)` and allows for a string as a key.

First, create a hashmap:

```
HashMap<String, Button> buttons=new HashMap<>(); //The <> works in JDK 1.7. Otherwise use new HashMap<String, Button>();
```

Then add the buttons:

```
buttons.put("name1", findViewById(R.id.but1));
buttons.put("name2", findViewById(R.id.but2));
```

and get them with:

```
Button btn=buttons.get("name2");
```

You can adjust the string used in `get(` to select the button.